# Owl ontology property chain example in Pizza Ontology

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I've been working on OWL Ontologies recently using Protege 4 and comes across a property called Property Chain.If the property P1 relates individual A to individual B, and property P2 relates individual B to individual C, then property P relates individual A to individual C. 
For Eg: 
A parentof B ancestorof C → A ancestorof C
Can anybody give an example using Pizza Ontology?

Answer (score 1):

The property hierarchy of the Pizza ontology is not very wide, but another example would be: hasIngredient o hasSpicyness SubPropertyChainOf hasSpicyness. That way, if we have PizzaMargherita1 --hasTopping--> Chilli --hasSpicyness--> Hot we also get PizzaMargherita1  --hasSpicyness--> Hot. Unfortunately, if you take this instance of the Pizza Ontology: http://protege.stanford.edu/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl

hasSpicyness cannot be functional in this case, if you want to use a reasoner (non-simple property!).